# How do I enable keyboard shortcuts in Outlook 2003?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

How can I enable the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> shortcut to send emails in Outlook 2003?

When I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, nothing is sending. It was working just before I install a MS Dynamics CRM package. There are GPOs configured for the whole business but as an SysAdmin, I don't get that impact.

Comment: What happen when you try to use it?  Are there any group policies applied to the computer?

Comment: When I hit Alt-S, nothing is sending. It was working just before I install a MS Dynamics CRM package. There are GPOs configured for the whole business but as Sys adm role, I don't get that impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete this key:

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version (11.0)>\Outlook\DisabledShortcutKeysCheckBoxes 
Value name: AltS 
Value type: REG_SZ (String Value) 
Value data: 16,83
```

---

(Approximate step by step instructions:

1. Start, Run, type Regedit press OK
2. Navigate through the folder tree to:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook
   ```
3. Look for the key above
4. Delete it
5. Close the Registry Editor and restart Outlook for the changes to take effect)

Comment: I thought that was to fix it but I don't have that Key in my registry.

Comment: The only other option would be to uninstall, because Outlook 2003 dosen't offer customized keyboard shortcuts...

Comment: I had to reinstall... that fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but AutoHotKey should provide you with a quick workaround for the time being.
You can download it [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/). And speaking of Outlook you may just alter the macro [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Macros.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it but the integration with Outlook doesn't seems to work. Also, as far as I remember, this is something custom in Outlook... any idea?